# Left adjoint of forgetful functor $\mathbf{Field}\to\mathbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

In Basic [Category Theory by Tom Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf), it is mentioned in Examples 2.1.3 that the forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{Field}\to\mathbf{Set}$ has no left adjoint. A proof is given later in Example 6.3.5, for which I don't have the knowledge yet.

My goal is now to intuitively understand where this fails. As a beginner, I feel like the left adjoint functor of $U$ should just be "the functor $F:\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Field}$, where for a set $S$, we define $F(S)$ to be the "field generated by elements of $S$ in which no unexpected relations hold". For instance, if $x$ and $y$ are elements of $S$, then $F(S)$ will contain the elements $x$, $x+y$, $\frac xy$, some elements $0,1\not\in S$, and so on.

I assume that $F$ is not the left adjoint of $U$ because $F$ does not even exist. Is this correct? Why is this?

Comment: As a bonus hint on top of Joshua Tilley's answer: What would the characteristic of $F(S)$ be? How does this impact its ability to map into other fields (injectively, as has been noted)?

Comment: Since no unexpected relations hold, the characteristic of $F(S)$ should be $0$. We can this not map $F(S)$ into fields of non-zero characteristic.

Comment: I guess with this argument, we do not even need to assume that $F(S)$ is the field which is freely generated by $S$? It suffices to say that $F(S)$ has some characteristic, and we can thus not map $F(S)$ into another field $K$ of different characteristic? And thus there are no morphisms $F(S)\to K$, but at least one morphism $S\to U(K)$. From this, we can conclude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct about what a left adjoint functor *should be* - freely generated by the set. Formally, this is a consequence of adjunction:
each ring homomorphism $f:F(S)\to K$ from the free field on a set $S$ into a field $K$ is uniquely determined by the restriction map $f|_S:S\to K$.

Now if you want to try and see why there is no functor $F$ with this property, *explore the consequences* of this condition. What do you know about field homomorphisms?

Comment: Field homomorphisms are in particular injective.

Comment: Nice. Perhaps you could try and construct a non-injective homomorphism after assuming that such a functor exists...

Comment: OK, I will try. Thank you!

Comment: To my mind, the essential property of field homomorphisms which prevents a "free field on generators" from existing is: such homomorphisms only exist between fields of equal characteristic.